# copy const wchar_t * to a temp

Tags: visual-c++

Program gives me an error at here.
Program has stopped working error.
I am using VS2010 and I have included wchar.h

```
const wchar_t * string = L"This is a wchar string.";
wchar_t * temp = L"";
wcsncpy(temp,string,5);
```

Any idea why this happens?
thanks.

Comment: This shouldn't compile - you are declaring the same name twice. And using an identifier `string` that was never declared.

Comment: Because both variables point to strings in the read-only section of your binary? Because the destination string is smaller than the source? So many things...

Comment: Sorry in my code its is string and declared as string.

Answer (score 0):

I had to initialize temp with new keyword.
Reason is temp needs to assign unknown number of memory space to store the copy.
Other wise it tries to copy the things to its current memory space.